# Get data from users(table) Where id of users(table) equals to id of friends(table)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've tried to get data from from one table if id of 2 tables equals to each other. Here is the code which I used:

```
SELECT id_to
     , email_to
     , name_to
     , status_to  
  FROM users 
  LEFT 
  JOIN friends 
    ON users.id = friends.id_from 
 WHERE id_from = ?
```

I used LEFT JOIN to join two tables but it gets the values from the friends(table) instead of users(table).

I think I've explained my problem clearly.

Comment: I disagree. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you must specify it on your query, like this:

```
SELECT users.id_to, users.email_to, users.name_to, user.status_to  FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON users.id = friends.id_from WHERE id_from = ?
```

You can do the same if you need to retrieve values from 'friends' table.

Comment: Oh! I see same answers, :P

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have the same column, then you can specify the table name while selecting columns. so your code will look like:

```
SELECT users.id_to, users.email_to, users.name_to, user.status_to  FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON users.id = friends.id_from WHERE friends.id_from = ?
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` is an oxymoron